# unable to pass null to execute(); method of AsyncTask in android 4.0

Tags: android, null, android-asynctask

i am trying to pass null value to execute(); method of AsyncTask in android 4.0 it show error
"The method execute(Integer[]) is ambiguous for the type" but same code is work fine with android 2.2 Code is :

```
public class AllianceAnalysisDemoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new AsynPageLoader().execute(null);
}


public class AsynPageLoader extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null && result.getHeight() > 0
                && result.getWidth() > 0) {

        }else {

        }
    }

}
```

}

please help  me how to pass null value .execute(null); method in android 4.0

Comment: Why you want to pass null? If you don't want the Integer value as a parameter to AsyncTask?

Comment: reduce the number of references to an object by assigning null.
if object is no longer referenced so it will be available for the garbage collection i.e. the compiler will destroy it and the free memory will be allocated to the other object.

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325277/why-does-system-out-printlnnull-give-the-method-printlnchar-is-ambiguo

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work:

```
new AsynPageLoader().execute((Integer) null);
```

Comment: thanks RC. its work fine with integer but what about Void data type  Ex>

class UpdataColumnTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   
   return null;
  }

 }

Comment: is there other way to reduce the number of references to an object by assigning null