# Why does `System.out.println(null);` give "The method println(char[]) is ambiguous for the type PrintStream error"?

Tags: java, null, system, println, system.out

I am using the code:

```
System.out.println(null);
```

It is showing the error:

```
The method println(char[]) is ambiguous for the type PrintStream
```

Why doesn't `null` represent `Object`?

Comment: `System.out.println((Object)null);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to pass null to execute(); method of AsyncTask in android 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679739/unable-to-pass-null-to-execute-method-of-asynctask-in-android-4-0)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033037/how-is-an-overloaded-method-chosen-when-a-parameter-is-the-literal-null-value

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are 3 `println` methods in `PrintStream` that accept a reference type - `println(char x[])`, `println(String x)`, `println(Object x)`.

When you pass `null`, all 3 are applicable. The method overloading rules prefer the method with the most specific argument types, so `println(Object x)` is not chosen.

Then the compiler can't choose between the first two - `println(char x[])` & `println(String x)` - since `String` is not more specific than `char[]` and vice versa.

If you want a specific method to be chosen, cast the null to the required type.

For example :

```
System.out.println((String)null);
```

Comment: I know and understand this concept. But for sake of the completeness of the answer, does the JLS somewhere specify why, for example, `char[]` and `String` are equally specific? After all, `char` is a primitive and `String` is an object.

Comment: @Magnilex char is a primitive, but char[] is an object. char[] is not a sub-class of String and String is not a sub-class of char[]. Therefore neither one of the two is more specific.

Comment: @KannanThangadurai note that you can write `char x[]` as `char[] x` - many (e.g. [Google's style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.3.2-array-declarations)) prefer the latter form because the type of `x` is `char[]`, not `char`. Keeping the type together makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 8):

If you call `System.println(null)` there are multiple candidate methods (with `char []`, `String` and `Object` argument) and the compiler can't decide which one to take.

**Fix**
 Add an explicit cast to null.

```
System.out.println((Object)null);
```

Or use [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

---

> ***Why does't `null` represent Object?***

From [JLS 4.1 The Kinds of Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null,
>   which has no name.
> Because the null type has no name, it is impossible
>   to declare a variable of the null type or to cast to the null type.
>   The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null
>   type. The null reference can always be cast to any reference type.
> The null reference can always be assigned or cast to any reference type
> <sup>In
>   practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend
>   that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference
>   type</sup>

So the type of `null` is **not** `Object`, though it can be converted to (read-as assigned to) an `Object`.